# Update content of node in JCR 2.0

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr

I try to update node in JCR 2.0

```
InputStream content = node.getProperty("jcr:content").getProperty("jcr:data").getBinary().getStream();

//TODO same with stream
Binary value = ...;

Node contentNode = node.getProperty("jcr:content");
contentNode.setProperty("jcr:content", value);
```

And I get exception "javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: Item is protected". What`s wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "jcr:content" you're referring to is typically the name of a child node (usually of type nt:resource, or something similar), rather than a property. Thus your code sample should rather be:

```
// read value
Binary value = node.getNode("jcr:content").getProperty("jcr:data").getBinary();

// update value
Binary value = ...;
node.getNode("jcr:content").setProperty("jcr:data", value);
```

See also the putFile() utility methods in the [JcrUtils class](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.2/org/apache/jackrabbit/commons/JcrUtils.html) of the jackrabbit-jcr-commons library.